# How To Get Specific Response Json?

Tags: postman

```json
{
  "id": 115084015,
  "from": "help@email.ncloud.com",
  "subject": "Verify Code",
  "date": "2022-12-27 19:53:45",
  "attachments": ,
  "body": "  Verification Code : 9906 Enter the code to sign up!  Keep this code to yourself, and no other action is required. "
}
```

how do I want to retrieve the submitted code that appears from the json response?

I want to get just the response code to put in the variable value

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question but on Postman you can see the statut code right at the header after you send your request.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to get `9906` from `body` part.

```js
const res = pm.response.json();
let body = res.body;
const regex = /\d{4}/gm;

//console.log(regex.exec(body)[0]); //9906
pm.environment.set("code", regex.exec(body)[0]);
```

Comment: Hello there, how do i add it to the variable?